# generate randomly disordered mixture

Tags: c

I'll edit this quetion: I want to arrive exactly as in the 2nd picture,does anyone have an idea or reference on how to generate this evenly random distribution.
I'm trying to generate randomly points A and B (NA=514 NB=513) as a mixture of points  in rectangle in C language using this

```
for(i=0;i <=par.Na-1;i++) { 
    do { 
        coo[i][0] = w * ran1_fast()  ; //ran1_fast a random number from 0 to 1
        coo[i][1] = Le * ran1_fast()  ;
    } while(mindist2(i) < sd2) ;

    //similarly for B
    for (j = par.Na+1; j <=(par.Nb+par.Na)-1; j++) { 
        do {
            coo[j][0] = w * ran1_fast() ;
            coo[j][2] = Le * ran1_fast()  ;
        } while(mindist2(j) < sd2);
```

With the above, I'm getting the below figure.  How could I edit this so that I have perfectly random points and not is overlapping on the other (like a disordered mixture) - see the 2nd figure.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The image (a) only has random sizes. It's pretty much ordered in its positions.

Comment: image A it's spaced but not ordered in a sense that you have one line A one line B the particles are distributed randomly but in a specific position

Comment: What does this have to do with MATLAB?  I'm removing that tag as there is no reference to MATLAB in your post.

Comment: I have formatted your code but it has various syntax errors leaving its intention unclear. Can you please provide code that needs attention on a slightly higher level than debugging typos, preferably the code that compiled?? TU.

Comment: What does `mindist2()` do?  It doesn't appear to be working if you are trying to keep points from overlapping.

Comment: midist2 means minimum distance between the particles but I can cancel it, the problem is that I don't know how to implement this in my code that's why I'm asking : how to generate such a picture as in image(a) it's ok if the script is in matlab or C language I just need an idea

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930796/generating-random-points-with-defined-minimum-and-maximum-distance

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

- Distribute all of your points (in this case, 1027) evenly
- Select 513 of them randomly and put them into one category, the other one into the other

As an additional watchout, self-rolled 'fast' random number generators are often not very good.  Beware the advice in Numerical Recipes:

"If all scientific papers whose results are in doubt because of bad [random number generators] were to disappear from library shelves, there would be a gap on each shelf about as big as your fist."

Here is some code, untested and not guaranteed to work.

```
    int temp[2*par.Na-1][2];

    for(i=0;i <=2*par.Na-1;i++) { 
        do { 
            temp[i][0] = w * ran1_fast();
            temp[i][1] = Le * ran1_fast();
        } while(mindist2(i) < sd2)  // I left this, but it could be an (almost) endless loop.

   for (i=par.N1-1; i>=0; i--)
      {
         int npick;
         npick = ran1_fast() * i;  // Pick an element randomly. Can your random number generator return 1? Then fix this.
         coo[i][0] = temp[npick][0];
         coo[i][2] = temp[npick][1];
         temp[npick] = temp[i];    // Copy down the last element.  
      }
```

// Second part of the copying left as an excersise to the reader.

Comment: yes ok,but I'm having problem in coding this can you please expalin more mathemetically