# Random points inside a circle: denser in the center, but avoiding overlap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, procedural-generation

I have a function that generates random points in C# in a way that I generally like; the points are denser in the center and become less dense in outer regions of the 'circle':

```
public static IPoint[] GeneratePointsAsCircle(int maxPoints, float scale,
    float radius = 26)
{
    IPoint[] points = new IPoint[maxPoints];
    int count = 0;

    while (count < maxPoints)
    {
        double r = rdm.NextDouble();  // rdm declared outside function, in class
        double theta = rdm.NextDouble() * 2.0 * Math.PI;
        double phi = rdm.NextDouble() * Math.PI;
        double sinTheta = Math.Sin(theta);
        double sinPhi = Math.Sin(phi);
        double cosPhi = Math.Cos(phi);

        double x = r * cosPhi;
        double y = r * sinPhi * sinTheta;

        IPoint point = new Point(x * scale, y * scale);

        /* Here is where people usually suggest a for-loop that checks the overlap
           by calculating the distance to see if its range of the radius
           (see function args), and then finding a new point if it
           does overlap. Problem is, its inefficient for larger number
           of points.

        example in pseudo-code:
        overlapping = false;
        foreach(other in points) {
            distance = GetDistance(point, other);
            if (distance < (radius*scale) + (radius*scale))
                 overlapping = true;
                 break;
        }

        if (!overlapping)... */
        points[count++] = point;

        // let run x-amount of times before breaking the loop to prevent
        // a forever loop.

    }

    return points;
}
```

If the point on screen has a radius of one, I don't think there is overlap. However in Unity, I have a UI Image with a radius of 32. So is there a way to efficiently account for the radius so it doesn't overlap in the way I've been able to generate the randomized points?

Alternatively, is there a Poisson Disc type of algorithms for circle shapes rather than a grid? Also, alternatively, what other ways can I prevent overlapping of random points in a circle that is not brute-force (if possible)? (I know these types of questions have been asked before and the solutions offered are usually something brute force-y like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XATr_jdh-44). I'm looking for something more efficient if possible.)

Comment: What is instead of adding your points to an array, you add them to a List that you keep ordered in the X-axis? When checking the new point, you figure out where it would fit in the list using a binary search, and then you check all the points to its left until the x diff becomes larger than twice the given point radius, and then you do the same to the right. If it isn't overlapping, you insert it to the list.

Comment: Could probably be even more optimized if you did like square sections with the width of the given point diameter using a 2d List. Then you could keep it kind of sorted in both axis. When adding a new point, you'd have to check it against points in  4 squares

Comment: Most of your randomiser can be replaced with ```Random.onUnitSphere() * radius```.

Comment: @Immersive you probably mean `Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized * radius` ;) A) this is in 2D and B) it's properties not methods

Comment: @derHugo My bad, yes, property.  But in this case we want the 3D-to-2D conversion (by zeroing/ignoring an axis) as that's how the weighted-to-centre is achieved. I meant ```on```, because ```in``` messes with the cosine distribution.

Comment: @Immersive oh .. So you mean `var randomPoint = (Vector2) Random.onUnitSphere * radius;` .. that's actually pretty clever, haven't thought about that!

Comment: Is it an option to define all the positions that a 32-radious image could be, defining them in a way that allows to fill the total area with the maximum number of non-overlapping positions, and finally just select randomly a subset of these positions? This would severally reduce the total number of different possibilities, but it might be good enough for your case.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - if you do that it can be really "regular" looking (depending on the application).   generating "random looking stuff" is a real art form in games.  humans are unbelievably good at seeing patterns.  in some cases when you take the approach you mention, the human experience is "on they just have dots on a grid"

Comment: i swear paper.js has this built-in so you could just port the code, but I can't remember where it is ... http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/

Comment: @ShamPooSham heh did you just "think that up" on the spot?  if so you basically invented spatial hashing on the fly, congrats  :)  :)  if you notice my answer there's a link to a kD tree which you'll like

Comment: @Fattie yeah, you are right. Although I was not thinking about a rectangular grid, but more of a grid produced by concentric circles, differing by 32 pixels in radius. I guess that the pattern would start becoming apparent at about 5% fill coverage or more.

Comment: @Fattie lol, I think we might have done something similar in some algo class a long time ago, but I don't remember the details and if they had a name for the algorithm. I know we did some algorithms with distance checking and drew some lines as a grid, so it might definitely be it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what other ways can I prevent overlapping of random points in a circle that is not brute-force

Sure, use Delauney triangulation.  As I remember there's even a handy library, script, someone wrote delauney in c# for Unity.

- as everyone has said, use the existing random functions to simply choose random points in a circle
- regarding the video link you posted, it is so long I couldn't find the technique the guy is using!  what is his technique?  just pure brute force?
- be aware that brute force is incredibly quick. You don't bother doing the actual distance, just box them (like Manhattan distance), the vast majority get eliminated on one axis anyway
- if you muck about with www stuff, D3 has everything you need, eg

https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph

A reminder too that the processing involved is trivial, don't waste too much time optimizing!

### If (for some reason) performance truly matters:

The best you can do is just use spatial hashing.

(Which is nothing more than "brute force" - ie check them all - but you cut the surface or volume up in to boxes. Then you know you need only check the items in that or adjacent boxes.)

Mathematically it's just a **Kd tree**.

There's no faster way.

In fact someone already gave such an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9070925/294884

Every single video game you've ever played, is doing spatial hashing a zillion times a second!

Comment: Well for Delaunay triangulation, you need the points first, no?

Comment: well sure, you seed it up first.  will try to find some sample code ...

Comment: Def looking up KD Tree now. Thanks!

Comment: lol cool !  I am mystified why you need an efficient solution (are you doing vast numbers of these every second?) but sure, you will love doing it w/ a kd tree !

Comment: not necessarily. I have ~1000 points but when I use the second for-loop (see code in post) to look for overlaps, it slows down substantially. That, or it does not produce the desired amount of points.

Comment: fair, 1000 is a lot BUT your code at "example in pseudo-code" is really wasteful!  you just check if X is within the distance.  only in the few cases where X is within the distance, then check if Y is within the distance.

Comment: Oh i think i see, because it won't be overlapping if x-values are different. Only if the x-values are the same do you want to be checking the y-values. Ok ok... and hence the k-d tree... its a fast lookup. So then, do you think even with ~1000 points, i can get away without the k-d tree?

Comment: I totally forgot about KD trees.  Good Call!

Comment: @ACour008 - it really depends on your situation; do you do it "10 times a second" or "once when the user arrives on a level" or what.  it's really worth learning to engineer KD trees if you're a hobbyist or professional.  don't forget though. **in a real actual game, most usually what you do is what someone mentioned above: during development, just make say 10,000 such patterns, save in a small file, and in the actual game ...... just choose one of those randomly. that's how you most typically "actually" do this**

Comment: @Immersive - right, spatial hashing is, indeed, what "the whole world runs on" now; every single thing in a game engine (occlusion, physics, etc etc) is either 2d or 3d spatial hashing, all the world's processors are doing immense amounts of spatial hashing from millisecond to millisecond as we speak!  so techniques like a kd tree are a basic.

Comment: @Fattie yes you're right. although, no, it would not be happening 10 a second, it would still be worth learning. I'll try both ways, why not :P

Answer (score 0):

### Why not just use poisson disk ?

OP you mention you like using poisson disk sampling:

https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/

All you do is do it in a square, and, throw away items outside the circle. That's a tiny inefficiency and no problem.